# How display user role in view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I would like to display the role in the view in ASP.NET Core. I log in to the application and I have info: Hi {User}, you have permission: {permission}.

How to do it? I was looking for various guides but there is nothing mentioned about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the roles stored in claims:

```
@foreach(var claim in User.Claims){
   <p>@claim.Value</p>
}
```

Further you can filter them by Type "Role"

```
@foreach(var claim in User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "Role")){
   <p>Role: @claim.Value</p>
}
```

Comment: How return only name role ?

Comment: @DominikN You'll have to elaborate, because Role is a single value.